# How to hold UIview and Move?

Tags: uitouch

I wanted to `hold` UIView and `Move` like the way we all can change our icon on `home screen`.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a simple UI call that will do this for you.

It would be possible to implement using the following sequence:

- Detect a touch down event within the view.
- Time the touch down period to reach a threshold where you're confident the user intends to move the view.
- Once the threshold is passed, use some visual indication to indicate the view is moveable.  This could be a animated wobble, like with the homescreen icons, or something more simple.
- Track touch events as the user moves the view, and update its position accordingly to remain under the user's finger.
- When the user lifts their finger (a touch up event), set the view's position to the new location (possible with some snap to grid, as used on the homescreen).
- Detect some event to restore the view to its non-movable appearence. The homescreen uses the home button, but you could just use the touch up event.

Hope that helps.  There's quite a bit of coding required there, and much of it is specific to your UI and design choices.